# Search for .xls file within current active directory and subdirectories

Tags: matlab

My company uses an in-house Matlab script to reduce data from some of our test equipment. This script is hosted on a Dropbox folder that anyone within the company can access and, if they have Matlab, run.

The directory for the script and experimental files is organized in the following manner:

```
C:\Users\EmployeeName\Dropbox\Laboratory\ReductionScript\Device1\ProductTest
```

The `\ReductionScript` directory contains the main reduction script and some other functions. Running the script involves placing the raw data files within the ProductTest folder, performing "Add To Path -> Folders and Subfolders" on `\ReductionScript`  and executing the ReductionScript in the Command Window from within the correct `ProductTest` folder.

The output from this scrip is placed within the ProductTest folder. This has worked for years now, and when opened on an individual's copy of Matlab, updates to show the nuances of the directory leading up to `\ReductionScript`

The problem that I'm having now is that we want to update the script to write to an excel file in another directory to make a record of test history. The excel file it writes to would be persistent and unique to the product we're testing. So, one day we might test a product, record it's test data to the test history .xls file, then a month later test it again, and want to write more data to that same .xls file. My plan is to store the test history .xls files in a folder within the `\ReductionScript` directory. Example:

```
C:\Users\EmployeeName\Dropbox\Laboratory\ReductionScript\TestHistory
```

What I cannot for figure out is how to perform a search for a target .xls file in TestHistory while at the same time allowing the script to run on multiple systems with unique directory paths (i.e., Employee1, Employee2, etc.).

Comment: [mfilename](https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mfilename.html) allows you to receive the full path of the file currently running.

Comment: Furthermore, you can most likely use a relative path like `.\TestHistory` (I don't use Windows, might be the wrong syntax).